# SQL 3 column query on condition

Tags: mysql

I'm still pretty new to SQL and have a table something like the following

```
Street     |  Family  |  Car
--------------------------------
Mayfair    |  Jones   |  BMW
Mayfair    |  Jones   |  Ford
Mayfair    |  Jones   |  Mazda
Mayfair    |  Smith   |  BMW
Mayfair    |  Fox     |  BMW
Park Lane  |  Taylor  |  Ford
Park Lane  |  Taylor  |  Mazda
Park Lane  |  Cole    |  BMW
```

I was wondering if there is a single query that can be done to check a particular street, to see if there is a car that all the family's have?

So for instance in the above table the query would only return BMW for Mayfair as all the family's on Mayfair own a BMW.

I'm only using XAMPP at the moment with MySql so don't have any fancy server or anything setup etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT street, car 
FROM tableX AS t1
GROUP BY street, car
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT family)
       = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.family)
           FROM tableX AS t2
           WHERE t2.street = t1.street
         )
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT street, car               --- show streets and cars
FROM tableX AS a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS                          --- where there is no
  ( SELECT Family                         --- family
    FROM tableX AS f
    WHERE f.Street = a.Street             --- in that street
      AND NOT EXISTS                      --- that hasn't
        ( SELECT Car
          FROM tableX AS c
          WHERE c.Family = f.Family      
            AND c.Car = a.Car             --- that car
        )
  )
```

Comment: The `SELECT Family` and `SELECT Car` can be replaced by `SELECT *`. I only put them there to make clear how the query works.